# How to combine both Navigation drawer and bottom navigation bar in android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

Is it possible to combine both the navigation drawer and bottom navigation bar at same activity in android? I am able to use them on separate activities but am facing difficulties while combining them in a single activity.

Comment: any solution found?